# OnKeyDown doesn't work for IE9 but works for everyother browser

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I'm trying to get the onkeydown property to run a JS function that just has an alert, it works on Chrome and FF but not in IE9. Neither keydown, keyup nor keypressed work on IE9. This is the code I used for testing:

JS:

```
function method()
{
   alert("hi");
}
```

ASP:

```
<asp:TextBox id ="tb" runat = "server" onkeydown = "method();"/>
```

I tried calling it like this `onkeydown = "method();"` and like this `onkeydown = "method(); return false;"` and neither worked.

By the way, on the program I'm planning to implement this, the textBox has an extender. Regular HTML won't work here ^_^'

Also, I can't post too much of the original source due to clients request to keep it closed source.

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are getting any error message...

Comment: how to use `onKeydown` have a look [here](http://www.javabeat.net/jquery-keydown-keypress-keyup/)

Comment: @user3588674 no error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my approach from `OnKeyDown` to `OnMouseMove` to simulate a threaded loop. Called it on a div that enclosures the whole page. This div doesn't do anything, it's purpose is to call the `OnMouseMove` function, that way I can do the same thing I wanted to do with the `OnKeyDown`. Thanks for the support!

Comment: Changed it again and now calling `SetInterval` when document is ready instead of `OnMouseMove`.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote the code and i just need to change the method name to work.

I was using `onkeydown="method()"` but when i change to `onkeydown="methodXX()"` the magic works. And of course i change JavaScript code.

Comment: This. It could very well be related to the [`method` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms534167.aspx) exposed by Internet Explorer. Although it's supposed to only be applicable to `<form>` elements and not to be global. Then again, that's IE, so who knows.

Comment: My function's name, on test environment, is BBQ and still wasn't working. Didn't post it like that cause it's silly and I was pretty sure it won't change

Comment: Can you share a fiddle with us?

Comment: My test is pretty much what I posted here but with BBQ as function name and Monkey as textBox id. I don't think it's necessary to show the code of the program I want to use it in cause I already figure what to do when it's called. Also, its quite long and my client prefers to be closed source

Comment: In theory, if it works with this test it should work on my program cause all I need is to call the function from that control. But if you REALLY need it to formulate a suggestion, I'll see what I can do.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I, sometimes, think MS projects start off being designed by humans and implemented by donkeys

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Code would look like this,

```
<input id ="tb" runat = "server" onkeydown = "method();"/>
```

Comment: I need the event to be fired when a key is pressed not on clicks, but thanks for suggesting

Comment: My apologies, I misread the question. In his case, I would open up F12 developer tools to analyse what is going on. I have always had issues with the samething, I just noticed he is using asp.net textbox control instead of an input control, I would advise changing to a input control and adding runat="server in the tag, this will have the same results as above and will work :)

Comment: It would've work, but the control I'm aiming for, in the original program, it has en extender tied to it. But it's a great suggestion

Comment: You never said that in your original question, I would stay away from extenders, they are an ugly way to do stuff.

Comment: Yeah, they can be annoying, but some can be pretty useful.